# Get last two segment of ip address using Ansible

Tags: string, ansible, ip, cut

I have a playbook that grabs ip address as below.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] *************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [mwiwas01] => {
    "hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address']": "10.0.12.15"
}
```

However, I wish to get the last two segments of an ip address i.e only `12.15`.

Note: the ip addresses would change on each host hence I m looking for a standard solution that is compatible to work for any given IP version 4.

How can I grab the same from the IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `split` function .

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'].split(".")[3]+hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'].split(".")[4]
```